# Create stored procedure in SSAS Tabular model

Tags: stored-procedures, ssas, ssas-tabular

Is it possible to create a stored procedure in SSAS Tabular Model? I need to invoke  a stored procedure from a Fact table in SSAS Tabular model. The results are stored in a temporary table. My client does not want the stored procedure to be stored as an object  on the database.

Answer (score 0):

[Importing to Tabular via a Stored Proc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/725091cb-ebe8-4587-8c36-1c55de596659/importing-to-tabular-via-a-stored-proc?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

This link here should be the answer to your question.

I think something to be mindful of is whether or not your temp tables' results will produce a predictable column output.